# influence of crossover operator on result

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I wrote a simple genetic algorithm using one point crossover, one point mutation, and tournament selection to solve the one max problem for 64 bits. The size of the population is 100. I wanted to see the influence of the crossover operator on the result. So I run the algorithm on a 0 probability for mutation 20 times, and took the mean of the best results, per iteration of the algorithm. I repeated this 5 times changing the probability of using the crossover operator acording to this formula p_crossover = 1 * 0.95^(n-1), n is the number of test. The results surprised me a bit. I know the rule of thumb is to set the crossover probability relativly high to fully exploit the information in the population. But why doesn't it affect the result linearly? The first 3 test gave very similar mean results: 61.5 (prob = 1), 61.5 (prob = 0.95), 61.35 (prob = 0.9025), then the las two  60.45(prob = 0.8574), 60.5 (prob = 0.8145). Can somebody explain this?
[image: picture showing the 5 tests of the algorithm]

Edit:I took a second attempt running the algorithm not 20 but 50 times. Now the mean results look like this, so it seems as if outliers caused this behaviour.

[image]

Comment: What is the y axis showing?

Comment: @NPE Ups! sorry I didn't check if it's in english. That's the mean of the 20 runs, at a certain iteration of the algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure if your results are very surprising. If you only run it 20 times, the results can be skewed pretty easily if you have an unlucky streak where you might have one or two instances where the probability treshold isn't reached. Do you get similar results when you run this more often?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel could you sugest a number of times i should run this. Is 40 enough?

Comment: Run it with a few different values (40, 100, 1000) and see how it evolves. If the results are gradually closing in on eachother then it's probably a matter of outliers that affect the solution less and less, if they stay as distant then it might be something else.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I run it 50 times and now the results are rather regularly spread. Would you delete this question or might this be useful for somebody?

Comment: @Lukasz: totally up to you. You can leave it up and add an answer yourself that shows what the problem was. I would suggest to clean up the question a bit though to make it more easily readable.